# Rails new command not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I run `rails new search` in my console, and I get all of this:

```
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -J, [--skip-prototype]      # Skip Prototype files
  -T, [--skip-test-unit]      # Skip Test::Unit files
  -G, [--skip-git]            # Skip Git ignores and keeps
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]   # Path to an application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
      [--dev]                 # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to your Rails checkout
  -b, [--builder=BUILDER]     # Path to an application builder (can be a filesystem path or URL)
      [--edge]                # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository
      [--skip-gemfile]        # Don't create a Gemfile
  -d, [--database=DATABASE]   # Preconfigure for selected database (options: mysql/oracle/postgresql/sqlite3/frontbase/ibm_db)
                          # Default: sqlite3
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]           # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                          # Default: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
  -O, [--skip-active-record]  # Skip Active Record files

Runtime options:
  -q, [--quiet]    # Supress status output
  -s, [--skip]     # Skip files that already exist
  -f, [--force]    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -p, [--pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes

Rails options:
  -v, [--version]  # Show Rails version number and quit
  -h, [--help]     # Show this help message and quit

Description:
    The 'rails new' command creates a new Rails application with a default
    directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.

Example:
    rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog

    This generates a skeletal Rails installation in ~/Code/Ruby/weblog.
    See the README in the newly created application to get going.
```

But it doesn't actually create the application. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

turns out I needed to install the rails gem again: `gem install rails`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `rails new ./search` ?

I just tried it in windows, Ruby 1.9 w rails 3.0.9 and didn't have that problem.

Answer (score -2):

If you're using RVM, try creating a new gemset and then install rails.

```
rvm gemset create better
rvm gemset use better
gem install rails -v x.x.x
rails new betterApplication
```

Comment: -1 for being so damn childish - try and be a little more professional in future.